# sum all values in specific hours of date dsl queries

Tags: elasticsearch

I have index contains docs looks like this:

```
"_source": {
               "price": "11",
               "loggingdate": "15/02/2016 08:56:58",
            }
```

I need a query that sum all values in price values between 10:00 - 12:00 **in this year**

I need total of each hour(10:00,11:00,12:00) This gives me total 3 hours of the result(only 1 item in bucket) but I need in seperated for each hour(three item in bucket)

```
    {
   "size":0,
   "query":{
      "filtered":{
         "filter":{
            "bool":{
               "must":[
                  {
                     "range":{
                        "loggingdate":{
                           "gte":"now-1y"
                        }
                     }
                  },
                  {

                  },
                  {
                     "script":{
                        "script":"doc.loggingdate.date.getHourOfDay() >= 10 && doc.loggingdate.date.getHourOfDay() <= 12"
                     }
                  }
               ]
            }
         }
      }
   },
     "aggs": {
    "by_hour": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "loggingdate",
        "interval": "hour"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "total": {
          "sum": {
            "field": "price"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**result:**

```
"aggregations": {
      "by_hour": {
         "buckets": [
            {
               "key_as_string": "15/01/2016 10:00:00",
               "key": 1452852000000,
               "doc_count": 58453,
               "total": {
                  "value": 2106110494
               }
            },
            {
               "key_as_string": "15/01/2016 11:00:00",
               "key": 1452855600000,
               "doc_count": 23243,
               "total": {
                  "value": 849522038
               }
            },
            {
               "key_as_string": "15/01/2016 12:00:00",
               "key": 1452859200000,
               "doc_count": 11994,
               "total": {
                  "value": 430906409
               }
            },
            {
               "key_as_string": "17/01/2016 10:00:00",
               "key": 1453024800000,
               "doc_count": 1,
               "total": {
                  "value": 0
               }
            },...
```

I think I need use range with date_histogram but how can I sum all price values in other docs date_histogram gives me only docs in range..

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically need a [`range` filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-range-query.html) to select only documents of the desired year and then another [`script` filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-script-query.html) in order to only select documents with the hours between 10am and 12am. Finally, you simply need a [`sum` aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-sum-aggregation.html) to sum all the prices of the matching documents.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "range": {
            "loggingdate": {
              "gte": "2016-01-01",
              "lt": "2017-01-01"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "script": {
            "script": "doc.loggingdate.date.getHourOfDay() >= min && doc.loggingdate.date.getHourOfDay() <= max",
            "params": {
              "min": 10,
              "max": 12
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "total": {
      "sum": {
        "field": "price"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**UPDATE**

If you need the total by hour, you can use this aggregations instead:

```
  "aggs": {
    "by_hour": {
      "terms": {
        "script": "doc.loggingdate.date.getHourOfDay()"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "total": {
          "sum": {
            "field": "price"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for quick response. I edited question for my point I think I didnt make it clear. I want to get the total sum of price for each specific hour in buckets. This query smilars mines return only one buckets that sum all of three hours